# Change the automatic text generated from f.label

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, text, label

I have the code

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <div>
    <%= f.label :email, :class=>'inline betaLabelTextField' %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class=>'betaTextField' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that this code automatically generates the html

```
<div> 
        <label class="inline betaLabelTextField" for="user_email">Email</label> 
        <input class="betaTextField" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" /> 
    </div>
```

Inside a form. How can i change 'Email' to 'Email Address'?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way is to do this instead:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <div>
    <%= f.label :email, "Email Address", :class=>'inline betaLabelTextField' %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class=>'betaTextField' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @moritz (below) answer is more the Rails way. The main important aspect is to stay DRY. When defined in activerecord:models:attributes: you will a) avoid unnecessary code and b) will always have the correct word in each form per language

Comment: How can you modify all f.label, adding at the end, for example, a ":".. How can you modify the class?

Answer (score 8):

This is done by adding appropriate i18n values to config/locale/en.yml. Please have a look at the guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models for the format of that file for active record values.

Comment: This is a way to do it, but it's unnecessary unless you're already doing internationalization.

Comment: I wouldn't say its unnecessary. I think, it just depends on where you want to keep this data. If you consider namings to be separate to the views, it makes sense to keep them in the translation files. So it sort of comes down to a matter of taste.

Comment: I guess you're right. When I think about it, your way will update the label everywhere, in case it's used somewhere else.

Comment: Definitely some necro here, but in case it helps others (or myself, the next time I have to google this), there's a nice example of this in the [documentation for the label method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label).